# SQL CONCAT Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a Concate like:

CONCAT(OEEL.orderno+'-'+OEEL.ordersuf+'-'+OEEL.prodcat) AS "Unique"

```
    SELECT        OEEL.invoicedt, UCASE(OEEL.whse) AS Whse, OEEL.orderno, OEEL.ordersuf, OEEL.custno, UCASE(OEEL.shipto) AS Shipto, UCASE(OEEL.slsrepin) AS Slsrepin, 
                         UCASE(OEEL.slsrepout) AS Slsrepout, OEEL.returnfl, OEEL.netamt, OEEL.wodiscamt, OEEL.discamtoth, OEEL.qtyship, OEEL.commcost, ICSS.csunperstk, 
                         UCASE(ICSD.name) AS Name, UCASE(ICSD.region) AS Region, UCASE(OEEL.prodcat) AS Prodcat, UCASE(SASTA.descrip) AS Descrip, UCASE(OEEL.transtype) 
                         AS Transtype, UCASE(ARSS.user2) AS User2, OEEL.transdt, ICSS.transdt AS "ICSS.Transdt", ICSD.transdt AS "ICSD.Transdt", SASTA.transdt AS "SASTA.Transdt", 
                         ARSS.transdt AS "ARSS.Transdt", { fn CURDATE() } AS CURDATE1, { fn CURTIME() } AS CURTIME2, 
                         CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.netamt - OEEL.wodiscamt - OEEL.discamtoth) ELSE (- 1 * (OEEL.netamt - OEEL.wodiscamt - OEEL.discamtoth)) 
                         END AS "SALES", CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.qtyship * OEEL.commcost * NVL(ICSS.csunperstk, 1)) 
                         ELSE (- 1 * OEEL.qtyship * OEEL.commcost * NVL(ICSS.csunperstk, 1)) END AS "COST", 
                         (CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.netamt - OEEL.wodiscamt - OEEL.discamtoth) ELSE (- 1 * (OEEL.netamt - OEEL.wodiscamt - OEEL.discamtoth)) END) 
                         - (CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.qtyship * OEEL.commcost * NVL(ICSS.csunperstk, 1)) 
                         ELSE (- 1 * OEEL.qtyship * OEEL.commcost * NVL(ICSS.csunperstk, 1)) END) AS GP

FROM            { oj { oj { oj { oj PUB.oeel OEEL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.icss ICSS ON OEEL.cono = ICSS.cono AND OEEL.shipprod = ICSS.prod AND OEEL.icspecrecno = ICSS.icspecrecno } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.icsd ICSD ON OEEL.cono = ICSD.cono AND OEEL.whse = ICSD.whse } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.sasta SASTA ON OEEL.cono = SASTA.cono AND OEEL.prodcat = SASTA.codeval } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.arss ARSS ON OEEL.cono = ARSS.cono AND OEEL.custno = ARSS.custno AND OEEL.shipto = ARSS.shipto }
WHERE        (OEEL.cono = 1) AND (OEEL.invoicedt BETWEEN { d '2014-06-02' } AND { d '2014-06-03' }) AND (SASTA.codeiden IN ('C', 'c'))



ORDER BY OEEL.custno, OEEL.shipto, OEEL.prodcat
```

Comment: MySQL's CONCAT uses commas, not plusses. Other than that, what's the issue?

Comment: If for MySQL and all you want is the delimiters between the values then check CONCAT_WS().

Comment: it says there is to many variables specified

Comment: Since I'm not very smart, I have to keep things simple.  If I were trying to figure out how to concatenate strings in sql, I would start with a query that did that, and nothing else, from only one table.

Answer (score 0):

The function has + (which in MySQL is not a concatenation symbol) between the variables.

Try:-

```
CONCAT_WS('-', OEEL.orderno, OEEL.ordersuf, OEEL.prodcat) AS `Unique`
```

CONCAT_WS does a concatenation **With Separator** .the first parameter is the separator with the others concatenated together.